# Strange reg output

Tags: python, regex

I am using regular expression to identify days of the week and I have the following regular expression

```
(?:mon(?:(?:.)?|(?:day)?)|tue(?:(?:.)?|(?:sday)?))
```

My test file contains

```
monday
mon
mon.
```

When I run my code it recognizes `mond`, `mon`, and `mon.`. Why does it not recognizes `monday`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using python 2.7.6

Comment: I just tested this regex in JS : it does recognize "monday"

Comment: BTW asking a regex question without precising the language/flavour rarely makes sense. See the description of the tag.

Comment: @dystroy no it is not working have a look at **[this](http://rubular.com/r/nviXIekFj7)**

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian What fiddle ? Just type this in your console  : `/(?:mon(?:(?:.)?|(?:day)?)|tue(?:(?:.)?|(?:sday)?))/.test('monday')`

Comment: @dystroy check in the link provided by me..

Comment: @user2604504: Is `mon.day` valid for you?

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is fauly actually. Try this simplified regex:

```
(?:mon|tue(?:s)?)[.]?(?:day)?
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/jC2iW3

Comment: I tested OP's regex with monday. It works for me.

Comment: but that doesn't work for the "mon." case with the period at the end of mon

Comment: @dystroy: No it doesn't work. See this link: http://regex101.com/r/tA6lI7

Comment: @user2604504: It matches `mon` from `mon.` Do you want to capture DOT also?

Comment: yes I would like to capture the dot as well

Comment: @dystroy no it is not working have a look at **[this](http://rubular.com/r/nviXIekFj7)**

Comment: OK, that's what I said. Questions depending on the flavour and not precising the flavour should be closed.

Comment: @user2604504: Check updated answer and link.

Comment: @anubhava if you dont mind can you help me with tutorials for understanding the concepts of regex?

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian: For me best is this site: http://regular-expressions.info